# Pioneer Q&A question: How does the off-chain code get passed to the Wallet for execution

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

In the Week 1 lectures, Lars mentions that the off-chain code is to be executed by the Wallet; this makes sense as the Wallet has access to the Private Keys that would be essential in signing the transactions prior to submitting to the blockchain.

My question is, by what mechanism does the Wallets get the off-chain code to execute? How does the Wallet then know what order said code needs to be executed in (i.e., on the EnlishAuction a user needs to first 'start' the action prior to anyone being able to actually bid for the NFT).

Lastly, and this is probably covered in later lectures, how would Plutus off-chain code handle transactions that require signing from multiple Private Keys?

Comment: My intuition tells me it's being handled by Plutus Schema: [Schema](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/playground-common/html/Schema.html#t:FormSchema) This is just a guess however.

Comment: This should be edited to be a couple of generic questions (if not already asked).  There is nothing "Plutus-Pioneer" specific about "How does off-chain code get passed to the wallet for execution"

Comment: [ask] and [help/dont-ask] have good guidelines